Can the Independence Assumption in McDiarmid's Inequality Be Relaxed Using a Worst-Case Sensitivity?
McDiarmid's Inequality in its standard two-sided form is typically stated with the assumption that the variables $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are independent:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left( \left| f(\mathbf{X}) - \mathbb{E}[f(\mathbf{X})] \right| \geq t \right) \leq 2 \exp\left(-\frac{2t^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2}\right),
$$
where the $c_i$ values represent the sensitivity of the function $f(\mathbf{X})$ to changes in each variable $X_i$.
Let's consider a simple case where the function is the sample mean:
$$
f(\mathbf{X}) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
$$
If we define each $c_i$ as a constant representing the worst-case change in the mean function (e.g., $c_i = \frac{x_{\text{max}} - x_{\text{min}}}{n}$ for all $i$), does this allow us to relax the independence assumption in McDiarmid's Inequality? In other words, can the inequality still hold if the $X_i$ are dependent, given that we use a worst-case $c_i$ for the sensitivity?
To exemplify, if we have a sample $X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8]$ with $x_{max} = 10$ and $x_{min} = 1$, then in McDiarmid's Inequality, if we assume every $c_i$ to be bounded by $(x_{max} - x_{min})/n$, can we remove the independence assumption? This represents the worst-case change in the mean when any single element is changed.
Specifically:
Is it valid to use $c_i = (x_{max} - x_{min})/n = (10 - 1)/10 = 0.9$ for all $i$ in this case?
If so, can we apply McDiarmid's Inequality as:
$P(|\bar{X} - \mathbb{E}[\bar{X}]| \geq t) \leq 2\exp\left(-\frac{2nt^2}{(x_{max} - x_{min})^2}\right)$
without assuming independence of the $X_i$?
Does this approach generalize to any sample with bounded values, allowing us to apply McDiarmid's Inequality to means of dependent random variables?
This formulation seems to capture the worst-case scenario for changes in the mean. I'm curious if this reasoning is sound and if it indeed allows us to extend McDiarmid's Inequality to dependent variables in this context.
If not, are there any modifications or alternative concentration inequalities that can be applied in this scenario with dependent variables?
